# eliminar y crear un nuevo elemento en el DOM con JS y AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema a la hora de crear un nuevo icono.

Lo primero que hago es listar los usuarios a mediante un bucle:

```
    <div class='plan'>
                <h2 class='plan-title'><?php echo $nexo->getNombreModelo(). ' ' . $nexo->getApellidosModelo(). ' ' .$nexo->getId(). ' ' .$nexo->getConfirmacion() ?></h2>
                <h2 class='plan-title' id="costeHora"><?php echo $nexo->getCosteHora() . ' €/H' ?></h2>
                <img class='foto' src='../img/<?php echo $nexo->getFoto() ?>'>
                <ul class='datos-empleado'>
                    <li><strong>ID: </strong><?php echo $nexo->getIdEmpleadoModelo() ?></li>
                    <li><strong>DEPARTAMENTO: </strong><?php echo $nexo->getDepartamento() ?></li>
                    <li><strong>EMAIL: </strong> <?php echo $nexo->getEmail() ?> </li>

                   //con este método pinto los iconos
                    <?php echo $this->pintarAsistencia($nexo->getConfirmacion(), $nexo->getId() ); ?>

                    <div class="btn-anula-invitacion" data-id-costeEmpleado="<?php echo $nexo->getCosteHora() ?>"
                    data-id-reunion="<?php echo $nexo->getIdReunion_fk() ?>" 
                    data-id-nexo="<?php echo $nexo->getId() ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-slash"></i></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

este es el método con el que pinto esos iconos (el que llamo desde el bucle):

```
public function pintarAsistencia($valorConfirmacion, $idNexo){

    if($valorConfirmacion == 0){

        echo "<div class='btn-confirma-invitacion' data-id-nexo='".$idNexo."'><i class='fas fa-question-circle'></i></div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div><i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i></div>";
    }
}
```

Todo esto hace que se muestre una vista en la que aparece mi lista de empleados con los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando abro la página, el bucle llama a la BBDD y lee un campo en la tabla  del empleado que tiene 1 o 0. Si tiene 1, pinta un check verde, pero si tiene un 0, pinta una interrogación amarilla.

A la hora de confirmar la asistencia, quiero hacer click en la interrogación amarilla, que esta se convierta en un check verde y no se pueda hacer click de nuevo en ese icono.

Para eso he hecho lo siguiente:

```
    function confirmarInvitacion(e) {

//Recojo el btn-confirma-invitacion que pinto con mi método pintarAsistencia().

    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-confirma-invitacion')) {

//recojo este parámetro que voy a enviar al controlador
        const idNexo = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id-nexo');

        console.log(idNexo);
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Mando toda la información al controlador y este inserta mi registro.
        xhr.open('GET', `../controller/empleado_reunion_controlador.php?idNexo=${idNexo}&accion=confirmar`, true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                Swal.fire({
                    position: 'center',
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Asistencia confirmada',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                })
                setTimeout(() => {

//Aquí viene el  problema. Elimino el icono de interrogación (porque ya ha confirmado)
                    e.target.remove();

//creo un icono de check verde nuevo.
                    const iconoConfirmado = document.createElement('i');
                    iconoConfirmado.classList.add('fas', 'fa-check-circle');

//lo meto dentro de mi btn-confirma-invitacion.

                    const botonNuevo = document.querySelector('.btn-confirma-invitacion');
                    botonNuevo.appendChild(iconoConfirmado);
                }, 2000);
            }

        }

        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Ahora lo que ocurre, es que el icono de la interrogación se elimina y elcheck verde aparece en el primer registro que el DOM encuentra con un btn-confirmar-invitacion. Adjunto imagen de lo que ocurre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si refresco la página, todo se pinta correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que al hacer click en la interrogación, me pinte el check verde en el mismo registro en el que estoy?

Espero haber sido claro!! gracias por la ayuda!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes probar a añadir el icono verde antes de eliminar el del `target` puedes utilizar el contenedor padre del `target` para ubicar el icono verde. En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
    function confirmarInvitacion(e) {

//Recojo el btn-confirma-invitacion que pinto con mi método pintarAsistencia().

    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-confirma-invitacion')) {

//recojo este parámetro que voy a enviar al controlador
        const idNexo = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id-nexo');

        console.log(idNexo);
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Mando toda la información al controlador y este inserta mi registro.
        xhr.open('GET', `../controller/empleado_reunion_controlador.php?idNexo=${idNexo}&accion=confirmar`, true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                Swal.fire({
                    position: 'center',
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Asistencia confirmada',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                })
                setTimeout(() => {

//creo un icono de check verde nuevo.
                    const iconoConfirmado = document.createElement('i');
                    iconoConfirmado.classList.add('fas', 'fa-check-circle');

//lo meto dentro de mi btn-confirma-invitacion.
                    const botonNuevo = e.target.parentElement;
                    botonNuevo.appendChild(iconoConfirmado);

// Elimino el icono de interrogación (porque ya ha confirmado)
                    e.target.remove();

                }, 2000);
            }

        }

        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude. Saludos

Comment: SIII perfecto!!!! Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: ahora me queda otra duda!!! ¿como hago para que cuando se ponga el check verde se quite el eventListenner? 
Si vuelvo a hacer click en el icono verde, no causa ningún problema en la BBDD, pero el javascript vuelve a ejecutarse. He probado a hacer un removeEventListener del listener que ya tengo pero eso hace que se eliminen los listener de los demás registros y tenga que refrescar para poder poner los check verdes...

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre para eliminar un evento de un componente es `iconoConfirmado.removeEventListener("click", confirmarInvitacion);` justo despues de añadirlo a `botonNuevo` pero ya lo has probado, lo que no entiendo es como es que elimina los listeners de todos los elementos

Comment: Es que lo probé antes de consultarlo aquí. Ahora no me elimina los listeners del resto, simplemente no hace nada. Cuando hago click en la interrogación, cambia a verde, y si vuelve a hacer click en el check verde, se ejecuta de nuevo la función. Lo he colocado justo debajo de `botonNuevo.appendChild(iconoConfirmado);` pero es lo mismo que si no pusiera nada.